# EC2 won't accept RDS incoming data without ALL TCP 0.0.0.0/0

Tags: tcp, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This appears to be a case of the opposite of the common condition. My EC2 instance won't accept incoming RDS (MySQL) data without opening ALL TCP to 0.0.0.0/0.

1. If in EC2 security group I allow ALL TCP 0.0.0.0/0, then the database works and site loads.
2. If I remove ALL TCP 0.0.0.0/0 entry from EC2 security group, but still have Inbound 3306 (MySQL) open to 0.0.0.0/0, the site won't load due to database connection timeout.

CentOS 6/MySQL
Both in same region

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed this issue it appears. In the EC2 Security Groups, I selected ALL TCP from the drop down list. In the address field, I entered the ID of the Database Security Group which was assigned only to my RDS instance. FYI, the RDS Security Group only had one port open 3306 (MySQL).

Amazon states that adding a security group to another security group will give all computers associated with the first security group access to whatever ports/services you assign.

Comment: Is there any security concern associated with this?

Comment: Faced the similar issue, because my EC2 and RDS belongs to same Security group, which I edited. Thanks for solution, to have separate group for every server.